# Em dynamically scaling for headers

Tags: css

I am setting up a page where the text is sized with `em` relative to a single parent. This allows me to change the font size in one place and affect the whole site. Here is an example of how it is working.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    Some Text
    <div class="child">
        Some Text
        <div class="child">
            Some Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent { font-size: 30px; }
.child { font-size: .8em; }
```

So the way I understand it is the first level will be 30px in size. Each child level is 0.8 size relative the parent. So the hierarchy should be like this: `30, 24, 19, 15, 12, 10`. When I test this, it is the case.

This is exactly how I want to set up my headers to work (`h1`,`h2`, etc). The higher the number the smaller the font size. The problem is that they wont be put into a tree like the rest of the site - they will be stand-alone elements.

So my question: Is there any way in vanilla CSS to make an elements font-size relative to another element? If not, are there any frameworks that will do this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about tweaking your em size for each heading type?

```
<div class="parent">
    <h1>h1 example</h1>
    <h2>h2 example</h2>
    <h3>h3 example</h3>
</div>

.parent { font-size: 30px; }
    h1 { font-size: .8em; }
    h2 { font-size: .6em; }
    h3 { font-size: .4em; }
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ry9YX/

You would want to set up the explicit sizing based on the conversions found in a tool like this: http://pxtoem.com/

Comment: Oh I see. So you are using the inheritance from the parent element and setting the direct children to variable sizes underneath. Awesome! Thanks for the tool, too. Perfecto!

Comment: You're welcome @AnthonyRaymond. Thanks for the feedback, and don't forget to accept if all is well here ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can only make the font size of an element relative to its parent’s font size or relative to the font size of the root element. So there is no way to make the sizing of elements based on nesting as described in the question, since a heading cannot be a descendant of another heading.

If you want to have a hierarchy where each heading level has font size that is 80% of the font size of the higher level, you simply have to calculate the products 80% × 80%, 80% × 80% × 80%, etc. This would mean a scenario like the following, assuming for simplicity that top level heading should have the same font size as copy text (which is hardly ever a good idea, but a conceptual reference point):

```
.parent h1 { font-size: 100% } 
.parent h2 { font-size: 80% }
.parent h3 { font-size: 64% }
.parent h4 { font-size: 51.2% }
.parent h5 { font-size: 40.92% }
.parent h6 { font-size: 32.16% }
```

(Instead of `80%` etc., you can of course use `0.8em`, with identical results.)

However, there is generally no need for such a geometric progression. The design of headings is typography, not mathematics. If size variation is used, it should depend on several factors, e.g. the use of bolding, italic, and other typographic devices.